# jQuery click(function(event) hyperlinks won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I can't figure out why the hyperlinks wont work when using a jQuery click event.

I would like 1 button to work as a link
and one as a jump to in the current page.

```
div class="shortcat">
<a href="test.html"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>Test Now</a>
<a href="#Learnmore"><i class="icon-picture"></i>Learn More</a>
</div>

//--------- jQuery ---------------//

jQuery(window).load(function() { 
        jQuery("#loaderInner").fadeOut(); 
        jQuery("#loader").delay(400).fadeOut("slow"); 
        $('.teaserTitle ').stop().animate({marginTop :'330px', opacity:"1"}, 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('.shortcat a ').stop().animate({marginTop :'65px', opacity:"1"}, 600, 'easeOutQuint');
});


$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mainNav ul a, .logo a, .shortcat a, .notBtn a").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target_top -80}, 800);
});


//-------------Highlight the current section in the navigation bar------------//
    var sections = $("section");
        var navigation_links = $("#mainNav a");

        sections.waypoint({
            handler: function(event, direction) {

                var active_section;
                active_section = $(this);
                if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

                var active_link = $('#mainNav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
                navigation_links.removeClass("active");
                active_link.addClass("active");

            },
            offset: '35%'
        });
```

First part is the HTML the second part is my script.js

I think the click function event is wrong.

When i remove the shortcut out of it the hyperlink will work but the jump to not anymore.

Will there be an easy fix?

Comment: try adding `return false;` at the end of the event.

Comment: Thank you for the reply could you point out where i need to add it, im not sure.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for any errors? By the way, you're using an strange mix of jQuery() and $(). It would be better if you only used one (preferably $()). It makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: after `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target_top -80}, 800);` before `});`

Comment: I don't understand the alter part, its already before the }); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go: this works well

http://jsfiddle.net/6g4j2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mainNav ul a, .logo a, .shortcat a, .notBtn a").click(function(event){

        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];

        if (trgt != undefined) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
            var target_top = target_offset.top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target_top -80}, 800);
            return false;
        }

  });
});
```

Comment: So  `if (trgt != undefined)`  means the target has no # in the link. Check out the jsfiddle link i sent, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

most likely the function from the click event fails here

```
var trgt = parts[1];
```

for the first link, because parts will be undefined